# java - animated gif leaving trail on movement

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, animated-gif

I tried displaying an animated gif in a JLabel by doing this...

```
Icon pikachu = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif"));
JLabel gif = new JLabel();
gif.setSize(60,60); 
gif.setIcon(pikachu);
this.add(gif); //this is a JPanel
```

Apparently, the gif leaves trails on its movements as seen here in this image...
[image]
The original gif is the one on the top left. I thought the gif was too fast or too slow, so I tried adjusting the speed (which is the bottom left). Unfortunately, it wasn't the cause for the trails left by the gif (the dark lines/parts on top of the tail and ear part of the one on the right is the trails I'm talking about).

I was wondering what causes this and how to fix it

Comment: (gif.setSize(60,60);  and rest code that probably used NullLayout) == JLabel has horizontal, vertical alingment, gap for test and (Image)Icon in API,

Comment: As mKorbel said, try first `gif.setSize(100, 100);`.

Comment: I tried changing the size, it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Wow, even uses the same gif.  The problem is Java doesn't support the dispose method of the gif (I don't know why, it just doesn't)

Comment: wow, was looking for similar problem but didn't see that...thanks for the link, sorry for the duplicate.